# Minecraft server local difficulty doesn’t change

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I’ve been on a server for a while and there have been questions from everyone (including the owner) about why the farms we make are really slow at generating mobs.

I just had a look out of interest on the debug menu and the local difficulty is 1.03 everywhere. Even in the Nether and The End. That’s after 150+ days.

Surely this should fluctuate over time and depending on the area you are in?

Is there a setting or something that would force this value to remain constant everywhere in the Minecraft world?

If so, what is it and can it be removed so that the difficulty can fluctuate as intended again?

We’re running a vanilla Minecraft server on 1.13.1

Thanks

Comment: Is it a Vanilla server?

Comment: @FabianRöling yeah. Vanilla server on 1.13.1.

Comment: Try making a new Singleplayer world in 1.13.1 and standing around in it for a while, then look at the local difficulty. If that increases beyond 1.03, try the same on a new server, if that also works, try it with a copy of your server.

Comment: @FabianRöling will try that tonight thanks. I did create a new single player world but it completely failed to run well. Not entirely sure why but at some points it was reporting 0 fps. Haha!

Comment: 1.13 has a very bad performance. Even on my pretty good PC it goes down to 25 fps in an empty world. But your server doesn't have that problem? Then you could use the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

Do /difficulity peaceful/easy/normal or hard
This will change the difficulity, even if you have locked it.